# Hyperfunctions supported at a point

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, schwartz-distributions, generalized-functions

Is it true that the space of hyperfunctions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ supported at 0 coincides with the space of Schwartz distributions supported at 0?

More explicitly, is it true that any hyperfunction supported at 0 is a finite linear combination of various partial derivatives of the delta-function?

If the answer is yes, a reference would be helpful.

Comment: See Schlichtkrull's book on page 6, where he gives the example $e^{1/x}$ as a hyper function (clearly supported at zero) which is not a distribution.

Comment: I don't understand why $e^{1/x}$ is supported at zero. It seems to me that its support is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Because it is holomorphic outside zero. See the first pages of Schlichtkrull's book on how hyper functions are described as boundary values of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Well, what I mean when saying that the support is 0 is that the restriction of the hyperfunction to $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ vanishes. Is it satisfied for $e^{1/x}$?

Comment: Yes. See Schlichtkrull's book.

Comment: I don't know much about hyperfunctions but I am not sure what "coincide" should mean here. A distribution is an element in the dual of smooth functions with compact support while a hyperfunction is an equivalence class of holomorphic functionals. I do not see a canonical way to map one set into the other… E.g. how should a hyperfunction act on a smooth function and how to make such an identification that respects all wanted rules (such as the rules for the derivative…)?

Comment: @Dirk: Distributions are canonically imbedded into hyperfunctions, see p. 5 in Schlichtkrull's book.

Comment: Ha! Page 5 is not available in google books for me, this explains my ignorance…

Comment: You can also look at the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction

Comment: @DeaneYang: I have seen this article. It is generally useful, but I could not find at this link any mentioning of hyperfunctions supported at a point. Apparently Corbennick is right. But in that case I would be interested to get a more explicit description of hyperfunctions supported at a point, if such a description exists.

Comment: Look at the last bullet under Examples.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Right! I missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true. Schwartz distributions with compact support inovlve only finitely many
differentiations (every such distribiution is a derivative of some order of a usual, integrable function). Hyperfunctions may involve infinitely many differentiations.
For example, in dimension $1$ you can take any entire function $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$,
and then $F=\sum a_n\delta^{(n)}$ is a hyperfunction with support at $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an explicit description of hyperfunctions supported at zero or it is too large?

Comment: Distributions were invented by Laurent SCHWARTZ (not Schwarz).

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth: Thanks for spotting this misprint. I corrected.